# Vertically centering text in Swift UI

Tags: swiftui

[image]

I want the "$0.00" to be in the middle of the screen but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is my code:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(String(format: "$%.2f", (dolaresVM.dolares.last?.v)!))
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)



        }.navigationBarTitle("Test")
            .onAppear(perform: self.dolaresVM.fetchDolares)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why you are adding Text to ScrollView? Do you want to add Text in middle of screen inside ScrollView?

Comment: You mean the title or the "$0.00"? Both are needed. I only added the ScrollView because of the title, it won't show up without it. I don't know if it's a bug or not.

Comment: It is showing up even if you don't add scrollview. Let me answer below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ScrollView` has infinite inner space for its children. The `VStack` can't take all of this space. So `VStack`'s height is defined by its content (in our case - `Text`).
Without `ScrollView` it will work like you want:

```
       var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(String(format: "$%.2f", 0)).font(.largeTitle)
            }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationBarTitle("Test")
        }
    }
```

Providing `idealHeight` for the `VStack` can be helpful as well. You can use `GeometryReader` to get the 'outer' height of the `ScrollView`:

```
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text(String(format: "$%.2f", 0)).font(.largeTitle)
                    }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, idealHeight: geometry.size.height, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }.navigationBarTitle("Test")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As we discussed above, you don't need ScrollView so can write `.navigationBarTitle("Test")` inside `NavigationView`. So that `NavigationBarTitle` and `Text("$0.00")` both will be display on your screen.

Here i put static value of Text, you can replace it with dynamic value which you are setting up from your Model.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("$0.00")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationBarTitle("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!